# Error while building android application using gradle via command line

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I'm working on a Java deobfuscation application for which I need to build multiple android applications from their source code using command line via gradle. I went to the directory of the project where the gradle folder and build.gradle and gradle.properties files are present and ran the command `gradle wrapper` in the terminal. This is what I got:

```
$ gradle wrapper
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':lib'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.novoda.release.internal.compat.gradle5_3.AndroidSoftwareComponentCompat_Gradle_5_3.
   > org/gradle/api/internal/java/usagecontext/LazyConfigurationUsageContext

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error and tell me if I'm doing something incorrectly?
Also can anyone explain or provide a suitable resource that explains how to build APKs from source code using gradle in a easy-to-understand manner?

Thanks and sorry for bad English.

My gradle version:

```
Gradle 6.5.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-06-30 06:32:47 UTC
Revision:     66bc713f7169626a7f0134bf452abde51550ea0a

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.11
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          11.0.8 (Ubuntu 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1)
OS:           Linux 5.4.0-42-generic amd64
```

My java version:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

EDIT: running `gradle init` gives the same result as above.

Answer (score 0):

You should execute `./gradlew` file with command `assemble{YourBuildVariantHere}`.

For example: `./gradlew assembleDevelopDebug`.

And then you should place your APK at `app/build/outputs/apk/your/build/variant`

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no script file called gradlew in the project directory which is why I ran the wrapper function in the first place in hopes of generating it.